# Numpy gradient of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gradient

I have a 2D array sinusoidal pattern and want to plot both the x and y gradient of that function. I have a 2D array `image_data`:

```
def get_image(params):
    # do some maths on params
    return(image)

params = (a, b, c)
image_data = get_image(params)
```

I use `numpy.gradient` to get the gradients:

```
gradients = numpy.gradient(image_data)
x_grad = gradients[0]
y_grad = gradients[1]
```

Plotting all three looks like:

[image: gradients]

This pattern is not at 45 degrees. I'd expect x and y gradients to be different. In my mind `x_gradient[i][j]` should be the gradient of `image_data[i][j]` with respect to the indexes either side and `y_gradient[i][j]` the gradient with respect to indexes above and below. Because the pattern is angled slightly, in `image_data` the gradient changes at different rates.

Am I misinterpreting my data or not understanding `numpy.gradient` output?

Comment: My guess is you're doing everything correctly.  And while it's possible that the two gradients *are* the same, from the pictures I don't think they are (try `print(np.all(x_gradient == y_gradient))`).  But even if they were, it's certainly possible for the two gradients to be the same depending on your generating function (it looks like `sin(a*x + b*y)` - which has periodic gradients)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think the gradients should be different. But the gradient shapes for the given function should have the same shape with different levels. Let's do it analytically:

[image: partial derivatives]

So you can see they both have the same shape. Add the color levels and you'll see the difference.